# clang error on Xcode 7

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clang

I wrote a code for traveling salesman problem. It's fine when variables are small. But when i try with big ones. I'm getting this error:

```
> ld: 32-bit RIP relative reference out of range (3600627839 max is
> +/-4GB): from __Z6canAddi (0x1000013A0) to _bisi (0x1D69D4C60) in '__Z6canAddi' from 
> 
> /Users/ErcumentKaya/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project_#3-djqdrvmtzfcbziddedoewgswszvk/Build/Intermediates/Project
> #3.build/Debug/Project #3.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o for architecture x86_64
```

I believe it's related to memory allocation. Is there any way to increase that?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a huge array on the stack? Don't do that.

Comment: @BaummitAugen But i need that.

Comment: No you don't. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I'm not familiar with vector.

Comment: You should change that.

Comment: @BaummitAugen But it's too late to change it

Comment: Allocate the array at run time. Declare it as a pointer.